# Questions about [@slack/bolt] package for configuring for Redistribution to make available for multiple workspaces

Tags: slack, slack-api

Looking to see if anyone could point me to any documentation on if Bolt [@slack/bolt] is configurable for using with multiple workspaces?  I am currently utilizing the Slack Bolt NPM package SDK to develop a Slack App, and have it working for a single workspace - but now I want to make it available for multiple workspaces.  I have it currently configured in the API settings for allowing Redistribution, but not understanding what needs to be done inside the App to enable the App to pick up event(s) triggered across multiple workspaces from the App.
I only seem to be able to make it work with 1 single workspace at a time.

I have scoured all available sources but can't find anything that can point me to the right direction.  I feel like there is something that I am not understanding or if it isn't a possibility with Bolt...

Development environment (NodeJS), working with the [Slack Bolt SDK from Slack]

Do things change for how you configure the client for a redistributable app?  (no longer passing in the signingSecret and token), and having to be initialized a different way?  I feel like I am missing something.  Can anyone point me to some documentation on how this is accomplished for making the app functional for multiple workspaces with the Bolt framework (if it is).  Or point me to a project with existing implementation of a project that currently exists as an example.

Thank you, I appreciate any help/feedback.

Does that requirere that new individual app instances of the app would need to be setup and running for each workspace (one app can’t handle all workspaces). Also does that mean that a new app has to be setup for each workspace so it can be configured with where to point to for it’s event handlers?  I was initially thinking that a single app could be the central app to handle multiple workspaces - and that additional work spaces would be able to add the app from the ‘Add Slack App’ button from the Redistribution settings of the single app.
I do currently have it setup to pull in and store the additional workspaces IDs and tokens and initializing them through the app const values (but having to setup each one as it own individual running app per workspace. But the big issue I am having is that the redistribution settings for the API only seem to let you specify 1 App endpoint to direct events to, but each app is setup as it’s own app in this pattern (so I would need to have 1 for each)

Comment: Hi @CodingRiot, did you manage to solve the problem? Would you mind sharing it here?

Answer (score 0):

If you build using the OAuth examples [here](https://slack.dev/bolt-js/concepts#authenticating-oauth), then it will work across multiple workspaces using a single instance of the app.

Instantiating the app would look like this in your code -

```
const app = new App({
  signingSecret: process.env.SLACK_SIGNING_SECRET,
  clientId: process.env.SLACK_CLIENT_ID,
  clientSecret: process.env.SLACK_CLIENT_SECRET,
  stateSecret: 'my-state-secret',
  scopes: ['channels:read', 'groups:read', 'channels:manage', 'chat:write', 'incoming-webhook'],
  installationStore: {
    storeInstallation: async (installation) => {
      // change the line below so it saves to your database
      return await database.set(installation.team.id, installation);
    },
    fetchInstallation: async (InstallQuery) => {
      // change the line below so it fetches from your database
      return await database.get(InstallQuery.teamId);
    },
    storeOrgInstallation: async (installation) => {
      // include this method if you want your app to support org wide installations
      // change the line below so it saves to your database
      return await database.set(installation.enterprise.id, installation);
    },
    fetchOrgInstallation: async (InstallQuery) => {
      // include this method if you want your app to support org wide installations
      // change the line below so it fetches from your database
      return await database.get(InstallQuery.enterpriseId);
    },
  },
});
```

One App ID === One instance, which can be installed on multiple workspaces once you [activate public distribution](https://api.slack.com/start/distributing/public).